# how to show uialertview in main thread from nsobject class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I tried to show UIAlertView in another thread(Main Thread). But it always goes to thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=1 address=0x0) error.

I Used following code.

```
if ([urlData writeToFile:attachmentPath atomically:YES]) {
    UIAlertView *sucessAlrt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:gaAppName
                           message:@"File has been Downloaded successfully"
                          delegate:self
                 cancelButtonTitle:nil
                 otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

   [sucessAlrt performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) 
                                withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; 
}
```

why it goes to bad access error ??

Comment: Which line of code causes the error? Is it showing the alert or when you tap on in the OK button?

Comment: [sucessAlrt performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; Yes! when I click the OK button its happen.

Comment: Your comment is contradictory. If the crash happens when you tap the OK button then the crash does NOT happen when you show the alert. The problem is most likely because the object showing the alert has been deallocated by the time the OK button is tapped. Since the deallocated object is the alert's delegate, the app crashes.

Comment: when I click OK button it goes to bad sector. Not in that line. So what should I do for it ?

Comment: The alert view's delegate has been deallocated by the time it tries to contact its delegate. Set the `delegate` property to `nil` instead of `self`. This assumes you don't need to do anything when the user taps OK.

Comment: Set the delegate property to nil instead of self. rmaddy 's answer is correct !

Comment: @Unheilig: why did you deleted comments?

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the `UIAlertViewDelegate` methods? And more importantly, has this object from which you're calling this stayed within scope during the alert? If it is released, you would receive an exception.

Incidentally, unless you need the app to do something when the user taps on the `@"OK"` button, you'd pass `nil` for the `delegate`. If you need the `delegate`, make sure the object is retained.

Comment: Rob - the problem was that `self` was deallocated after showing the alert. Since `delegate` was set to `self`, the app crashed when the user tapped the OK button and the alert tried to contact the deallocated delegate. None of your suggestions would help that situation.

Comment: @rmaddy Agreed, my first two observations would not, but if you look at my conclusion, that's precisely what I suggested.

Comment: It seems you added your conclusion while I was typing my comment. Never mind :)

Comment: Agreed. I've removed my `dispatch_async` suggestion, as that doesn't solve the problem, just leaving the `delegate` comments I had in my conclusion.

Answer (score -1):

I think when you click "OK" its goes bad access because uialertview is not created in main thread, but you're trying to access the uialertview from main thread, by clicking "OK" when the dialog appears.I misunderstood the question at first, sorry :D So putting the whole code in a gcd call should solve this problem. Instantiate the alertview in main thread, and run your selector in the main thread.

Comment: The solution is not to put the whole thing on the main thread. And if you put all of this on the main thread, then why use `performSelectorOnMainThread`?

Comment: Didnt notice it was performSelectorOnMainThread. I've edited my answer.

Comment: OK, so now your answer is basically the same as the original code. Please note that the problem has nothing to do with showing the alert. The original code showed the alert just fine.